# Zlib decompressobj vs decompress performance

Tags: python, zlib

Is there any performance downside of using the zlib decompressobj function instead of decompress?

I'm asking because a python app that I work with decompresses files using zlib. For the last few months everything was working fine, however, one type of the files grow over the server memory limit which made the decompress function to fail. Based on the doc I can switch to decompressobj function which works on chunks and can handle big files. The thing is that I have more usages of the decompress function and I'm thinking about changing all of them to decompressobj. Is it OK or it might make the code slower?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, [**premature optimization is the root of all evil.**](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth) Only optimize something once it *is* too inefficient, *in practice,* and you identified the resource hog (e.g. with profiling), and the effect is large enough to be worth the effort and added complexity (=extra maintenance burden down the line).

---

Both `zlib.decompress` and `zlib.decompressobj.decompress` implementations are in [`zlibmodule.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/zlibmodule.c) , as [`zlib_decompress_impl`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/zlibmodule.c#L324) and [`zlib_Decompress_decompress_impl`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/zlibmodule.c#L758), correspondingly.

They do not share code but their code is pretty much the same (as expected) and delegates to the same `zlib` C library functions.

So there's no difference which one to use raw-decompressing-wise.

There will likely be a tiny overhead with `decompressobj` with extra logic and repeated Python calls -- but if data are large, decompressing time will dwarf it.

- So whether the replacement of `decompress` with `decompressobj` is worth it (or will have any effect at all) is going to depend on whether memory, processor or I/O is the bottleneck in each particular case (positive effect if memory, negative effect if processor, no effect if I/O). (Thus go to the first paragraph for guidance.)

Comment: Thanks!!! I did not think about checking the functions implementations!